# How to implement Master-Client model using GKSession?

Tags: ios, client-server, gksession

I am working with GKSession right now. I want to connect more than 2 iPads with each other.

I am able to connect two of them using Bluetooth GKSession PeerPickerController. I am pretty much new to this stuff.

Can any one give me some pointers or links to tutorial that implement such model ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a [sample GKSession project](https://github.com/shrtlist/GKSessionP2P) that illustrates setup and teardown of a `GKSession` without using a `GKPeerPickerController`.

Comment: Thasts a gr8 pointer Marco. Thanks. But I do have couple of doubts in it. I don't see connectionTypeMask mentioned any where in the code and I did trail and run, I guess its connecting over WiFi and not Bluetooth. is that correct? Besides that it also does not specifies mode like peer/master/client. I have only one iOS device with me and I connected it with XCode Simulator. I am not sure whether it allows more than 2 devices connected to each other ?

Comment: GKSessionModePeer is specified in the setupSession method. The demo does not use a GKPeerPickerController hence no connectionTypeMask.

Comment: No device limit specified in the code. I've successfully tested it on a wifi network using Simulator and at least two other devices. Will you be accepting my answer?

Comment: Thats gr8 I have only one device so could not able to test more than two. Thanks a lot for helping me out.